# How do I stack widgets overlapping each other in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to stack widgets like this:

[image: coins]

I wrote the code below. However the coins are coming one after another with some default padding. How can I get something like the image above?

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(
      Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0, 
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0),
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0,
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use a [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) with [`Positioned`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) to achieve this:

[image]

```
class StackExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body:  new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          height: 500.0,
          width: 500.0,
          // alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: new Stack(
            //alignment:new Alignment(x, y)
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0)),
              new Positioned(
                left: 20.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0)),
              ),
              new Positioned(
                left:40.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0)),
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ;
  }
}
```

And this how you get some nice shadow drop so the icon stands out more:

[image]

```
class StackExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body:  new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          height: 500.0,
          width: 500.0,
          // alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: new Stack(
            //alignment:new Alignment(x, y)
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: const Offset(3.0, 0.0),
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  ]
                ),
                child: new Icon(Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0))),
              new Positioned(
                left: 20.0,
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: const Offset(3.0, 0.0),
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  ]
                ),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0))),
              ),
              new Positioned(
                left:40.0,
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: const Offset(3.0, 0.0),
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  ]
                )
                  ,child: new Icon(Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0, color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0))),
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: let's say we want to make this in the center of the screen ?
we need to change the left property in every Positioned Widget .right ?
`new Center(child: new StackExample())`

Comment: I am not sure why it is happening but when I try to set 
`alignment: FractionalOffset.center,` It is centered but it is being overflowed by some other element

Comment: i got the same problem, now i am trying to use `Positioned.fromRelativeRect`

Comment: Ah I know why, we need to explicitly set `overflow: Overflow.visible,` in the `Stack`

Comment: Ok so i am using this on my app. I have a listview (vertically scrollable) and each element has these stacked elements which needs to be horizontally scrollable. How would i achieve that?

Answer (score 44):

As of **November 2019** I'd like to add a second solution:

Using package: https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets

```
var widget1 = ...;
var widget2 = ...;

RowSuper(  
  children: [widget1, widget2],    
  innerDistance: -20.0,
  );
```

This will overlap row cells by 20 pixels.

The difference from this solution to the one using `Stack` is that `Positioned` widgets in a `Stack` don't occupy space. So you can't make the `Stack` the size of its contents, unless you know their sizes in advance. However, the `RowSuper` will have the size of all of its children widgets.

Note, there is also a `ColumnSuper`. *Also note I am the author of this package.*

Comment: This help me to reduce spacing between Column elements. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: This is filthy and I love it. Thank you.

Comment: the easiest. so far haven't seen any troubles with this approach

Answer (score 34):

I wanted something without dependencies and without hardcoded layout.
*You could enhance by making overlap use a media query to overlap in terms of %.*

```
 Widget overlapped() {
    final overlap = 10.0;
    final items = [
      CircleAvatar(child: Text('1'), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      CircleAvatar(child: Text('2'), backgroundColor: Colors.green),
      CircleAvatar(child: Text('3'), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
    ];

    List<Widget> stackLayers = List<Widget>.generate(items.length, (index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(index.toDouble() * overlap, 0, 0, 0),
        child: items[index],
      );
    });

    return Stack(children: stackLayers);
  }
```

Comment: IMHO this solution is much cleaner than the others

Comment: Such a nice solution!

Comment: Lol! This is much better than the recommended ones. Appreciate @Lee Higgins.

Comment: This gives you all the flexibility you need without an external library. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try my package ([signed_spacing_flex](https://pub.dev/packages/signed_spacing_flex)). It's exactly the same as a normal `Row` (or `Column` and `Flex`). But it also lets you set negative spacing which causes its children to overlap. You can also set which children should be on top when they overlap.

In your case it would be something like:

```dart
SignedSpacingRow(
  spacing: -12.0,
  stackingOrder: StackingOrder.lastOnTop,
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(
      Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0, 
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0),
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.monetization_on, size: 36.0,
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0),
    ),
  ],
),
```

It also works with expanded children if you need.

Comment: This worked great for me, because I am using expanded children, thanks!

Comment: This worked great for me, great drop in replacement. The options with Stack or the assorted_layout_widgets weren't ideal because they didn't support crossAxisAlignement or Expanded children as easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code on Profile Picture overlapped by camera image in flutter.

> Output:
> [Click here to view output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HDHx.png)

```
Container(
    constraints: new BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: 200.0,
      maxWidth: 200.0
    ),
    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new AssetImage('assets/images/profile.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        new Positioned(
          right: 0.0,
          bottom: 3.0,
          child: Container(
            constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: 50.0,
                maxWidth: 50.0
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color:Color(0xFFdedede),
                  offset: Offset(2,2)
                ),
              ],
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.photo_camera,
                  size: 34,
                  color: Color(0xFF00cde7),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Wraping your elements with `OverflowBox` and giving the `maxWidth` value will achieve this effect.

The following can be used in a row or a listview

```
 return SizedBox(
            width: 35, //--> list children will be 35 in width
            child: OverflowBox(
              maxWidth: 50, // --> allowing the child to overflow will cause overlap between elements
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                child: Text((index + 1).toString()),
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse variant based on [@Lee Higgins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6205147/lee-higgins)

```
const size = 32.0;
const overlap = size - 6.0;
final containers = [
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    width: size,
    height: size,
  ),
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.grey[400],
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    width: size,
    height: size,
  ),
];
List<Widget> stackLayers = List<Widget>.generate(containers.length, (index) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, index * overlap, 0),
    child: containers[index],
  );
});
return Stack(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd, children: stackLayers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Padding in Stack, If you want to previous avatar to overlap next avatar, you can do like this

```
Stack(
    children: [
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
            child: Image.asset('assets/icons/avatar3.png'),
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Image.asset('assets/icons/avatar2.png'),
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/icons/avatar1.png'),
        ),
    ],
)
```