# Adding widgets upon image -flutter, dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image like this [image]

and i need to add widgets upon this image. It should look like the contents are just on the mobile screen. I tried searching for a way but i dint get any. I tried using stack like this:

```
Container(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(60, 110, 60, 90),
            //body
          ),
        ),
        Container(width: 1000,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('Assets/Images/transparentMobile.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

It worked correctly on my phone: [image]

but on other phone it looks very different. How do i write a single code for multiple screens?

Comment: Did [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) help you get your answer?

Comment: thnx, i think i should try it

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838021/how-do-i-stack-widgets-overlapping-each-other-in-flutter

Comment: That helps me in arranging the widgets inside the image, but how do i set the widgets exactly upon the image

Comment: I dont know if your answer helps me, but il try and post the answer

Comment: I am kind of feeling to point a layout for you. I hope that should work. Will that do @Bensal ? If yes, than I will map a layout for you

Comment: I did not see any changes in your question @Bensal

Comment: @Alok Ive changed now

Comment: Great job @Bensal. The problem is normal, not every phone will be of same size, hence `Positioned` will not be same of every mobile image. We might wanna dig deeper to find the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stack widgets overlapping each other in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838021/how-do-i-stack-widgets-overlapping-each-other-in-flutter)

Comment: Not actually, because in the positioned widget , I will have to specify different size for different screen sizes

Comment: @Alok Thanks for your help. Ive posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got a way to do it. Instead of working hard on the code, i just cropped the image into 3 parts :

top : [image: top]

body: [image: body]

bottom: [image: bottom]

and added them to columns like this:

```
AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1/2,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('Assets/Images/Mobile/mobileTop.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill
                )
            ),
          ),
        ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('Assets/Images/Mobile/mobileBody.png',),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill
                  )
                ),
                height: 100,
                child: Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                      title: Text('My Application'),
                    ),
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Hello World!',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('Assets/Images/Mobile/mobileBottom.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

and the image now looks much similar on most of the devices now: [image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well done Bensal! My upvote for your effrots :) I am saving your answer, so that I can take benefit from it in the future :)