# How to overlay a list on a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you please tell me how to make the top list go behind the bottom list like Stack? If the first 3 elements of the list are shown in more detail, then the rest are hidden behind another list that overlaps it from below. I have attached a screenshot showing this effect. If you tell me how to implement I will be grateful.

Comment: you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838021/how-do-i-stack-widgets-overlapping-each-other-in-flutter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Bottom sheet widget. Please check below link for the sample. If still it won't help you then please let me know.

https://medium.flutterdevs.com/modal-bottom-sheet-in-flutter-dae05debbed2

Comment: It's not that much. I need the page to always have 2 lists. In the first top list, the first 3 elements are visible, and the rest are hidden behind the second bottom list so that it overlaps them like a Stack effect

Comment: Maybe you could wrap two Containers into a Stack Widget and put the second Container in an Align Widget and give the alignment you want, or just give the Container a padding on the top.

Comment: You can add two elements in stack. And give the elevation to uppar one.

Comment: And if these are 2 lists, will there be any problems if I put them on the Stack?

Comment: You mean two list on stack? One over other right?